# Java multiple type variable

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm using Slick2D to create a simple game, and I have a class that is the base for all the game objects, it has an Image variable. But now I'd like to add an object that is animated, so I need to use the Animation class rather than Image class.

However Image and Animation do not have a common superclass, despite having methods with the same signature (such as draw, getWidth, getHeight). I know they both implement Renderable, but that doesn't help with getWidth or getHeight.

So how can I have a variable that can be of type Image or Animation?

(in objective-c, you could have variable with type id);

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces. Overload `Image` and `Animation` if these are canned classes. Then you can refer to these classes collectively by your interface.

```
public class MyImageObject extends Image implements Drawable {
    public void draw() {
        this.builtInImageDrawMethod();
    }

    // implementations of getWidth() and getHeight()
}

public class MyAnimationObject extends Animation implements Drawable {
    public void draw() {
        this.builtInAnimationDrawMethod();
    }

    // implementations of getWidth() and getHeight()
}

public interface Drawable {
    public void draw();
    public int getWidth();
    public int getHeight();
}

public class Worker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drawable d1 = new MyImageObject();
        Drawable d2 = new MyAnimationObject();

        d1.draw();
        d2.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the classes that the OP is asking about are from a 3rd party library.

Comment: @Code-Guru Can still extend and composite, though. When libraries don't provide reasonable hierarchies it's often the only real choice.

Comment: Unless they're `final`, he can still subclass them and implement his interface. The implementations of the `draw()` method would then call the corresponding third-party methods.

Comment: (Added example of that above.)

Comment: Downvoter... what's your objection to this solution? Curious if you see something I don't.

Comment: I didn't downvote but your solution has drawbacks, being the one of them that your code it's tightly coupled to the library instead of providing a layer of isolation

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're looking for. If he's using a library it seems unnecessary to reimplement an entire class because you want to add one tiny feature. Tightly coupling through inheritance is one of the main benefits of an OO language like Java.

Comment: 1) OO inheritance is a means of designing **your code**, not an approach for creating mixin's or aggregates. 2) The chances of finding method-collisions with your approach is high; that's why Java doesn't allow to extend more than one class and also provides means to make classes `final` 3) Wrapping & delegation is one of the **basic design patterns** and can be implemented with minimum cost

Comment: what I mean is: your approach could work with very little effort but has several drawbacks, using a delegation pattern doesn't require much work and that provides with isolation and consistent code.

Comment: I disagree with your approach only because you literally may write hundreds of lines of code to make a class that looks exactly like the base class except for one additional feature. Yes, a wrapper could work here, I'm not disagreeing with that point -- but I think it's harder to initially code and more confusing to maintain than simple inheritance. That's my opinion and you don't share it. That's completely okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a variable with more than one type. This just isn't possible with Java.

However, you can create your own class hierarchy which delegate to the Slick2D classes. For example, you can do

```
public interface MyVisualObject {

    // List all the common methods here

}

public class MyImage implements MyVisualObject {
    private Image img;

    public MyImage(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    // Implement the methods here. For example:
    public int getHeight() {
        return img.getHeight();
    }
}
```

You can make a similar `MyAnimation` class. Then declare a variable as `MyVisualObject` which can be an instance of either of the two implementing classes.

Comment: The problem with making a wrapper class like this is now `MyImage` and `MyAnimation` classes need to expose as public every single public method that `Image` and `Animation` have. In a well-developed API there could be tens or hundreds of those methods. Each time he wants to use a new method that `Image` or `Animation` supplies, he needs to add those methods here and doesn't automatically get them for free.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you don't have `id` types as in Objective-C. But (as others have already stated) you can define your own abstract class (or interface) and replace the `Image` attribute with that class. Then just provide implementations for the specific types wrapping around the types you are already using.

```
public interface Graphic {
   public int getWidth();
   public int getHeight();
   // other methods
}

public class ImageGraphic implements Graphic {

   private final Image image;

   public ImageGraphic(Image image) {
      this.image = image;
   }

   public int getWidth() {
      return image.getWidth();
   }

   public int getHeight() {
      return image.getHeight();
   }

}
```

***Note**: The `AnimationGraphic` class would follow the same approach.*

I recommend this approach instead of the Tenner's one since this way your code doesn't depend on extending classes that might not exist (or might change) in the future. This way, when those code changes arrive you have little code to change with less hassle than extending from the library class.